# STR_TO_DATE() Returning NULL

Tags: mysql, xml, xml-parsing

I've looked at the other questions regarding STR_TO_DATE() and their solutions aren't working for my case. I've also read up and searched elsewhere to no avail.

I'm importing many rows of the following XML:

```
<Game>
  <id>21</id> 
  <GameTitle>Final Fantasy XIII</GameTitle> 
  <ReleaseDate>03/09/2010</ReleaseDate> 
</Game>

<Game>
  <id>31</id> 
  <GameTitle>Heavenly Sword</GameTitle> 
  <ReleaseDate>09/12/2007</ReleaseDate> 
</Game>
```

With the following SQL statement:

```
USE test;
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\mysql\\data\\test.xml'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE games
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Game>'
SET ReleaseDate = STR_TO_DATE(@ReleaseDate, '%c/%e/%Y');
```

GameTitle and ID are importing perfectly. I've tried using %m and %d and have ensured that the ReleaseDate column is the DATE datatype. All rows are writing NULL in the ReleaseDate column.

MySql is returning

```
2466 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'ReleaseDate' 
at row 1 1265
```

Thank you in advance for you help. StackOverflow has solved every problem I've really ever had without even having to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to assign something to the variable you're using with STR_TO_DATE, something like

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\mysql\\data\\test.xml'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE games (id, GameTitle, @var1)
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Game>'
SET ReleaseDate = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%c/%e/%Y');
```

Note that the syntax for `SET` in `LOAD XML` is described in the syntax for [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Oh wow, that definitely makes sense. I was thinking that the @ReleaseDates was calling from the XML document and not a variable. Also, ROWS IDENTIFIED BY is now throwing a syntax error since adding (id, GameTitle, @var1). I feel like you've pushed me one step further though!

Comment: plus switch back to use `%m/%d/%Y` as format string if it's sure that month and date are always 2-digit with leading zero

Comment: Thanks MikeD, did that too. Seems the only issue is the ROWS IDENTIFIED BY throwing 'unexpected ROWS_SYM' now that we've added the specific columns. Running it without the ROWS IDENTIFIED BY line causes it to effect 0 lines.

Comment: To alleviate the ROWS Identified BY syntax error, I replaced the <game> and </game> tags with <row> and <row>, removed the ROWS IDENTIFIED BY line, and the query runs without issue... but it doesn't seem to be overwriting the NULL values, although it isn't kicking back any errors now.

Comment: Weird. I must have been hitting a bug of some sort. I ended up having to pull the dates into a text column then ran "UPDATE games SET NewDate = STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%m/%d/%Y');" to propogate my DATE column. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I hope all your <Game> tags are enclosed by a single root element like <list> or so?